# Find the number of days for which 120kg of ration will be sufficient given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the number of days for which 120kg of ration will be sufficient for a family of 6 members if each member consumes 2.5 kg of ration per day?

options:

a) $6$ b) $4$ c)  $8$ d)  $10$

MyApproach:

For $1$ member $2.5$Kg of ration is required per day.For $6$ members, $6$ . $2.5$ Kg of ration is required per day.

Therefore,for $120$ Kg of ration in how many days

I made the equation like

$120$  .  d=$6$ . $2.5$=$1$ /$8$

I am getting Ans wrong.Why my equation is wrong.Please give me a HINT?

Comment: (No. of days)*(Ration consumed per day) = (Total ration)   which is ,  $d*(6*2.5) = 120$